# Android Cast Best way to show two simultaneous displays with Cast Remote Display

Tags: android, android-fragments, casting, display

I am trying to create a cast remote display program that will display the same message on both a phone screen and the TV. This display will have functions attached and will change based on the user pressing one button. However this has proved more difficult that it sounds as textviews and buttons as we know are all linked to only one activity and its corresponding layout. I want the tv to display a full screen view of the message while the phone will display the message on half and a remote control with buttons on the other half. I was researching ways to tackle this problem and was wondering if fragments is the only way to solve this problem. Can I link a button on an activity to change text in a fragment and have that fragment display both on the phone and TV with those changes? or should I have everything be a fragment the remote control buttons and the two displays?